# Get Header from HTTPClient.GetAsync [C#]

Tags: c#, header, getasync

I have a problem with GetAsync. When i execute the instruction i get this response from fidder.

[image]

Debugging I can find all headers except the Transport Header which has a parameter that I need, which is FID. How could I get this one?

Here's the code (myHeader is null):

```
AddUserAgent();
AddAcceptEncodingHeader();
var mainPageResponseMessage = await    
HttpClient.GetAsync(string.Format(Resources.Home, _machineKey));
mainPageResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
var myHeader= mainPageResponseMessage.Headers.Location;
```

And here's the answer

[image]

Comment: It's the Location header, which Fiddler groups under "Transport".

Comment: Location Header is empty and also ContentLocation

Comment: Show your code and the values the response object holds.

Comment: There it is. Thanks.

Comment: Seems that if AllowAutoDirect is set to TRUE, that value is not available.